# Unable to send selected dropdown value using mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
     List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
                    if (questions.IsActive)
                    {
                        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "1", Selected = true});
                        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = "0", Selected = false });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "1", Selected = false });
                        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = "0", Selected = true });
                    }


                    ViewBag.IsActive = items;

 @Html.DropDownList("IsActive", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.IsActive, new { @id = "IsActive" })
```

Here i have added dropdown in controller and selected value is binding in view as well but i am unable to send the updated value to controller

Comment: Is Value integer or string ?

Comment: it is boolean value

Comment: Then Try with Value=0 and Value=1 and check

Comment: where should i need to try in view or?

Comment: can you help me with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                  var isactive = $("#IsActive").val();
                    if (isactive == 1) {
                        isactive = true;
                        $("#IsActive").val(isactive);
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#IsActive").val('@Model.IsActive');
                    }
```

This is worked for me